# Set default language for new files

Tags: atom-editor

Newly created files in Atom are always "Plain Text". How can I change this so that new files will automatically be in another language, for example "Shell Script (Bash)"? I want to do this because auto indentation does not work with Plain Text files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Had this problem as well, there is a plugin called [default-language](https://atom.io/packages/default-language) that will do this for you.

Search atom for default-language, install and open its settings. Type the name of the language you want Atom to default to, e.g. Shell Script (if in doubt, copy from the language selection menu) in the Default Language field. Next time you open a script with no extension (or shebang) it'll default to the language you set.

Answer (score 5):

The following code, added to your `init.coffee`, will do what you're asking:

```coffee
atom.workspace.observeTextEditors (editor) ->
  default_scope = 'source.shell'
  original = editor.getGrammar()

  # If the editor has "null" grammar (aka unset)
  if original? and original is atom.grammars.grammarForScopeName('text.plain.null-grammar')
    default_grammar = atom.grammars.grammarForScopeName(default_scope)
    if default_grammar? # check if desired grammar is already loaded
      editor.setGrammar(default_grammar)
    else
      # grammar was not loaded yet, so add a callback as grammars load
      callback = atom.grammars.onDidAddGrammar (grammar) ->
        if grammar.id is default_scope
          # once we've loaded the grammar, set it and dispose of the callback
          editor.setGrammar(grammar)
          callback.dispose()
```

Things to note:

- The `init.coffee` file is where you can customize Atom without having to write a package
- The `observeTextEditors` method sets a callback that is called upon each `TextEditor` creation for currently open and future editors
- The code above:

  1. Checks the grammar that the editor was created with
  2. If and only if it is the default ("null") grammar, it sets the editor's grammar to the Shell grammar once it's loaded
  3. Disposes of the callback to check for grammar loading once it's done with it

This should solve the `TypeError: Cannot call method 'getScore' of undefined` that happens for the first file opened in a new window.

To default to a different grammar, just change the `default_scope = 'source.shell'` line to use the scope of whatever grammar you'd like.

Comment: This is causing an error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'getScore' of undefined`, see: http://pastebin.com/yzN2hPUu

Comment: @shrx Interesting, I got that with other iterations of the code. It might be a timing issue where the grammars aren't loaded yet. I'll have to take another look at this later.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, CTRL+SHIFT+L is your friend. It's unfortunately not a permanent solution, but nice to know about.

Of course, we'd prefer a more permanent solution. A couple of the other answers are now obsolete due to API changes in Atom. Below is a more up-to-date version. Inspiration initially came from [this discussion](https://discuss.atom.io/t/edit-set-file-associations/2650/4), but the other answers here seem to follow the same concept as well.

Place this in your init.coffee file (`File -> Open Your Init Script`):

```
extname = require("path").extname
fileTypes =
  ".wxs": "text.xml"
  ".wxi": "text.xml"
  ".wixobj": "text.xml"

nullGrammar = atom.grammars.selectGrammar("text.plain.null-grammar")
atom.workspace.observeTextEditors (editor) ->
  grammar = atom.grammars.selectGrammar(fileTypes[extname(editor.getPath())])
  editor.setGrammar grammar  if editor.getGrammar() is nullGrammar and grammar isnt nullGrammar
```

Basically, you define have an array of file types, and the grammars (AKA syntax highlighting) that you want to associate them with. Find each editor, find out if it has a selected grammar already, and if not, attempt to give it one if we find one.

The one issue I've had with this is that the syntax highlighting only works if you open files *after* you've already launched Atom; if you open a file that results in Atom launching (say by double clicking on it's icon in your favourite OS), syntax highlighting won't for that file until you re-open it.

Comment: **`CTRL+SHIFT+L`** is what I'm looking for. Thanks @vee

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a mapping in your `config.cson` file.

```
"*":
  core:
    customFileTypes:
      "source.shell": [
         "sh"
         "shell"
      ]
```

For mapping .sh and .shell files to shell script syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this bit of code: (you can can then change 'text.html.basic' to whichever syntax you require)

```
editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()
cursor = editor.getLastCursor()
valueAtCursor = atom.config.get(cursor.getScopeDescriptor(), 'my-package.my-setting')
valueForLanguage = atom.config.get(editor.getRootScopeDescriptor('text.html.basic'), 'my-package.my-setting')
```

For reference please see: Scope Descriptors @ https://atom.io/docs/latest/advanced/scopes-and-scope-descriptors