# Atom Grammar Detector

Tags: atom-editor, grammar

I routinely have to pipe files with no file extension into Atom for editing. The Atom grammar-selector core package allows me to change the grammar relatively easily. I'm wondering 2 things:

1. Can I make this package always fallback to something other than plaintext?
2. Is there a way that the filetype's grammar can be detected without a file extension? In my case, the files are always YAML. Seems that there could be a grammar-detector pkg that tries to determine the grammar from the file content rather than just a file extension.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default language for new files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661424/set-default-language-for-new-files)

Comment: The flagged question should help your the first question (default language). The second is different, so should be separated into its own question anyway. Both useful questions, though!